# Response received but no data was written to STDOUT or STDERR. (CodeWars)...?

Tags: javascript

JS Code:

```js
function toUnderscore(string) {
  var a = string.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === a[i].toUpperCase() && a[i] !== a[0] && parseFloat(a[i]) !== Number(a[i])) {
      a[i] = `_${a[i]}`;
    }
  }
  console.log(a.join('').toLowerCase())
}
toUnderscore('App7Test');
```

(CodeWars)...? it also says that

> "TypeError: string.split is not a function"

Comment: Your code is working fine as you can see in the demo.

Comment: According to my search engine CodeWars is a web site. It feels that you're asking a support question for that service rather than an actual coding question.